# Table grouping resets selected values when adding new item

Tags: sapui5

Here we have a very basic table with an <kbd>Add</kbd> button and grouping activated. When I select values for the existing items and then press the button to add a new row, my selected values are getting reset, but without grouping it works fine. Am I doing something wrong or is this a bug?

```js
sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(() => sap.ui.require([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/XMLView",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel" // sample model. Can be also an ODataModel.
], async (XMLView, JSONModel) => {
  "use strict";
  
  const control = await XMLView.create({
    definition: `<mvc:View xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
      <Table items="{
        path: '/tableItems',
        sorter: { path : 'group', group: true }
      }">
        <headerToolbar>
          <OverflowToolbar>
            <Title text="Test Table" />
            <ToolbarSpacer/>
            <Button id="addButton" text="Add" type="Emphasized" />
          </OverflowToolbar>
        </headerToolbar>
        <columns>
          <Column width="20rem">
            <Label text="col0"/>
          </Column>
          <Column width="20rem">
            <Label text="col1"/>
          </Column>
        </columns>
        <ColumnListItem vAlign="Middle">
          <Text text="{text}" />
          <Select forceSelection="false" width="100%" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
            <core:Item text="test1" key="test1" />
            <core:Item text="test2" key="test2" />
            <core:Item text="test3" key="test3" />
            <core:Item text="test4" key="test4" />
          </Select>
        </ColumnListItem>
      </Table>
    </mvc:View>`,
    afterInit: function() {
      this.byId("addButton").attachPress(onPressAdd, this);
      function onPressAdd() {
        const oModel = this.getModel();
        const aItems = oModel.getProperty("/tableItems");
        const newItems = aItems.concat({
          group: "3",
          text: "3-1",
          key: "3-1",
        });
        oModel.setProperty("/tableItems", newItems);
      }
    },
    models: new JSONModel({
      number: 0,
      tableItems: [
        {
          group: "1",
          text: "1-1",
          key: "1-1",
        },
        {
          group: "1",
          text: "1-2",
          key: "1-2",
        },
        {
          group: "2",
          text: "2-1",
          key: "2-1",
        },
        {
          group: "2",
          text: "2-2",
          key: "2-2",
        },
      ],
    }),
  });

  control.placeAt("content");
}));
```

```html
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
  src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/1.82.2/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
  data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.core,sap.m"
  data-sap-ui-theme="sap_fiori_3"
  data-sap-ui-compatversion="edge"
  data-sap-ui-async="true"
  data-sap-ui-excludejquerycompat="true"
  data-sap-ui-xx-waitfortheme="init"
></script>
<body id="content" class="sapUiBody sapUiSizeCompact"></body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the `growing="true"` to the `sap.m.Table`.

This enables [`GrowingEnablement`](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/GrowingEnablement.js) internally which prevents rerendering the entire ListBase (Table) when the target gets invalidated. Only the necessary item will be then appended to the table.

Generally, in order to optimize the rendering behavior, it's always a good practice to..:

- Enable the `growing` property if the table / list is editable, shrinkable, or expandable.
- Add `key: <propertyName with unique values>` to the ListBinding info object to benefit from the [Extended Change Detection](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/7cdff73f308b4b10bdf7d83b7aba72e7) **if** the model is a client-side model such as `JSONModel`. With an `ODataModel`, the `key` is automatically added by the framework.

```xml
<Table xmlns="sap.m"
  growing="true"
  items="{
    path: 'myModel>/myCollection',
    key: <propertyName>, (if 'myModel' is not an ODataModel)
    sorter: ...
  }"
>
```

Comment: Unfortunately enabling growing does not solve the problem :/

Comment: @Lumpenstein You have to put `growing="true"` to the table as a control property. I re-tried my solution with your code snippet from the question. Worked quite well.

Comment: In [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wofj6m5s/1/) and here in SO it works indeed, but somehow not in my project, even though I literarily copied the code now for testing. The only difference I see is that jsfiddle uses OpenUI5 Version 1.84.0 whereas in my project version 1.82.2 gets used.

Comment: Created a new empty project, copied the code, not working, any idea what could cause this ?

Comment: @Lumpenstein Hmm, not really. It's also hard to debug from here without the "copied code" from your project. You'd have to add more info to the question such as: how is the project structured? How are the relevant view and controller defined? Which model are you using? ...

Comment: I created a project from template 'UI5 App' and then copied the above code (+ growing="true") into the view1.xml and controller1.js. so I have a mvc:View>Shell>App>Page>Table structure

Comment: @Lumpenstein What is the 'UI5 App' template? Is it from Web IDE? Unfortunately, I don't have access to the Web IDE anymore.

Comment: Yes from the WebIDE. Lucky you I hate their WebIDE would love to use VSCode or Webstorm instead.